# The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

```
2022-12-31T00:48:58.789+05:30 ERROR 10168 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  authenticationManager defined in class path resource [com/ecommerce/admin/config/AdminConfiguration.class]
└──<-──┘


Action:

Despite circular references being allowed, the dependency cycle between beans could not be broken. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

```java
package com.ecommerce.admin.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.WebSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class AdminConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
      return new AdminServiceConfig();
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
         return authenticationManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
      provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
      provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
      return provider;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
               .csrf().disable()
               .authorizeHttpRequests()
                   .and()
               .formLogin()
                   .loginPage("/login")
                   .loginProcessingUrl("/do-login")
                   .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/index")
                   .permitAll()
                   .and()
               .logout()
                   .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                   .clearAuthentication(true)
                   .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                   .logoutSuccessUrl("/login/logout")
                   .permitAll();
           DefaultSecurityFilterChain build = http.build();
           return build;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.ecommerce.admin.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.WebSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class AdminConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
      return new AdminServiceConfig();
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
      return authenticationManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
      provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
      provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
      return provider;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
               .csrf().disable()
               .authorizeHttpRequests()
                   .and()
               .formLogin()
                   .loginPage("/login")
                   .loginProcessingUrl("/do-login")
                   .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/index")
                   .permitAll()
                   .and()
               .logout()
                   .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                   .clearAuthentication(true)
                   .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                   .logoutSuccessUrl("/login/logout")
                   .permitAll();
           DefaultSecurityFilterChain build = http.build();
           return build;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Circular dependency issue is coming because of this Bean present inside **AdminConfiguration** class. Here in method argument you are passing an instance of **AuthenticationManager**  and also creating another instance of **AuthenticationManager** using **@Bean** annotation. This is incorrect, please remove this and try again.

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
      return authenticationManager;
    }
```